# understanding minheap and heapSort method

Tags: java, heap, heapsort

I have this two classes and I am asking about the `heapSort()` method. how to implement it in the the `Test` calss, also, can you please check my `add()` method and my `smallestChild()` method?

For the `heapSort()` method, the method should sort the array in ascending order the algorithm is to traverse the array and add all the numbers to the array and them remove all the numbers and put them back into the array!! Honestly this algorithm confused me and I don't know exactly how to do that? does the `heapSort()` need a helper method? or how?

this is the first class `MinHeap`

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
public class MinHeap {
    private int[] heap;   // The heap.
    private int size; // the next index
    public MinHeap(int capacity) {
        heap = new int[capacity];
        size = 0;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public void add(int n) {
        if (size < heap.length) {
            size++;
            n = heap[size-1];
            int p = (size -1)/2;
            while(n != 0 && n < heap[p]) {
                swap(size, p);
                size = p;
                p=(size-1)/2;
            }
            size++; 
        } else {
            throw new HeapFullException();
        }
    }

    private int smallestChild(int current) {
        if(size < heap.length) {
            int left = current *2+2;
            int right = current * 2 +1;
            if(heap[left]>heap[right]) {
                return left;
            } else if(heap[right]>heap[left]) {
                return right;
            } else {
                return left;
            }
        } else {
            return -1;
        }       
    }

    public int remove() {
        if (size == 0) {
            // if size has no element to remove throw exception
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        } else {
            // hold the minimum element
            int minElement = heap[0];
            // set the minimum index to the highest index and decrement the size
            heap[0] = heap[size-1];
            size--;
            int p = 0;
               while(heap[p] > heap[smallestChild(p)]) {
                int c = smallestChild(p);
                swap(p, c);
                p = c;
            }
            return minElement;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            s += i + ": " + heap[i] + "\n";
        }
        return s;
    }

    public int[] toArray() {
        int[] a = new int[size];
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            a[i] = heap[i];
        }
        return a;
    }

    private void swap(int x, int y) {
        int temp = heap[x];
        heap[x] = heap[y];
        heap[y] = temp;
    }

    class HeapFullException extends RuntimeException {
        public static final long serialVersionUID = 8320632366082135L;
    }
}
```

the `Test` class where I should write `sortHeap()` method is:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Test {

    private static Random rand = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    testMinHeap();
    }


    public static void testMinHeap(){
        int[] a = initRandom();
        MinHeap h = new MinHeap(a.length);
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            h.add(a[i]);
        }
        print(a);
        System.out.println("Smallest: " + h.remove());
        int[] b = h.toArray();
        print(b);
    }

    private static int[] initRandom() {
        int[] a = new int[rand.nextInt(40)];
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = rand.nextInt(100);
        }
        return a;
    }


    private static void print(int[] a) {
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

how to writhe the `sortHeap()`?? 
please help me to understand it and get ready for my exam
thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your `add` method doesn't add anything to the heap; there's no code that puts the value of `n` into the array. And the code that's supposed to sift things up through the heap is incorrect. A correct version of `add` would be:

```
public void add(int n) {
    if (size >= heap.length) {
        throw new HeapFullException();
    }

    // place the item in the heap
    int pos = size;
    heap[pos] = n;
    size++;

    // move the item into position
    int parent = (pos-1)/2;
    while (pos > 0 && heap[parent] > heap[pos]) {
        swap(parent, pos);
        pos = parent;
        parent = (pos-1)/2;
    }
}
```

Your `smallestChild` method has several bugs.

```
private int smallestChild(int current) {
    if(size < heap.length) {
        int left = current *2+2;
        int right = current * 2 +1;
        if(heap[left]>heap[right]) {
            return left;
        } else if(heap[right]>heap[left]) {
            return right;
        } else {
            return left;
        }
    } else {
        return -1;
    }       
}
```

First, your have the left and right child indexes reversed. The left child should be `(current * 2) + 1)`, and the right child is `left +1`.

Second, you unconditionally check the children, even if doing so would index off the end of the heap. You need to make sure that the `current` node actually has children before you go checking to see which child is smaller. Something like this will do it:

```
private int smallestChild(int current) {
    int left = current*2+1;
    if (left >= size) {
        return current;
    }
    int smallest = left;
    int right = left+1;
    if (right < size && heap[right] < heap[left]) {
        smallest = right;
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

For your `sortHeap` method, I think you want something like:

```
public static void testMinHeap(){
    int[] a = initRandom();
    MinHeap h = new MinHeap(a.length);
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        h.add(a[i]);
    }

    // now remove things in order and add them back to the array
    int ix = 0;
    while (!h.isEmpty) {
      a[ix] = h.remove();
      ix++;
    }

    print(a);
}
```

Comment: @3noo6 If my answer solved your problem, you might consider marking it as the accepted answer.